# Why cannot conform to protocol with associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

I have following simple protocol:

```
protocol JSONParser {

   associatedtype JSONResult
   func parse<T: Codable>(response: Response, type: T) -> JSONResult

}
```

Function `parse` takes simple `Response` which is struct and takes `T` which is `Codable`. And here is how I implement this protocol:

```
struct AuthJSONParser: JSONParser {

    func parse<T: Codable>(response: Response, type: T) -> AuthResult<T> {

    }

}
```

It seems everything okay. But Xcode says that it does not conform to protocol. 
Here `AuthResult<T>` just for case:

```
enum AuthResult<Model: Codable> {
   case success(data: Model)
   case failed(msg: String)
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my implementation. I want to use generic functions, instead of generic structs.

Comment: AuthJSONParser.parse has to return a concrete type. There are a number of ways to address this, but it depends on your needs. Does AuthResult have to be generic? Can AuthJSONParser be generic? Whys is the parse method generic parameter `T` the same as the return value generic parameter `T`?

Comment: I think `AuthJSONParser` has a concrete return type. It returns `AuthResult<T>` where `T` is `Codable`. Why does it have number of ways to address?
1) Yes, `AuthResult` should be generic. 
2) I want to avoid `AuthJSONParser` to be generic. If it would be generic, then I would create different instances of it to each type. 
3) It takes `T` which is some struct that confirms to `Codable`. `AuthResult<T>` where `T` is also codable. They are the same.

Comment: Notice that if you have a return type of AuthResult<String> your compilation error goes away. That's one way to address the problem. Another solution is to make AuthJSONParser a generic struct.

Comment: You mean that `String` does not confirm to `Codable` and anyways compiler doesn't warn?

Comment: String does conform to Codable. And right, if you specify the generic parameter type of AuthResult the compiler does not complain.